# "indirect" variables in foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to draw three "graphs" which are rectangles situated side-by-side. Each has four points to be placed on them. These four points are the "scores".

Using a `foreach` loop is a natural for the graphs, since all the layout and labels are the same.

What I can't figure out, is how to pass the list of data to each iteration. In other languages, I'd use something like a nested `foreach`, using an indirect variable whose name points to the data to plot, to place the data points. I can't seem to find variable indirection in tikz.

At present, it seems that the second \foreach is only seeing one value, rather than a list of four items. I may be using the wrong method. So other strategies welcome.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

% Use A4 page shape. 
% Base size of one graph is A4 page, but with pt instead of mm.

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\scale}{1.75}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\graphHeight}{297 pt/\scale}   
\pgfmathsetmacro{\graphWidth}{201 pt/\scale}

\def\labelsM{85, 10, 55, 75}
\def\labelsC{75, 20, 55, 65}
\def\labelsP{65, 30, 55, 55}

\def\graphInfo{ Graph one/{(-\graphWidth pt, 0pt)}/\labelsM,
                Graph two/{(0pt, 0pt)}/\labelsC,
                Graph three/{(\graphWidth pt, 0pt)}/\labelsP
                }



\foreach \name/\pos/\values in \graphInfo
        {
    % Draw box
    \node    [
                at = {\pos},
                draw, 
                rectangle, 
                line width = 2pt,
                minimum width = \graphWidth pt,
                minimum height = \graphHeight pt,
                fill = black!15,
                name=\name
                ] 
                {} ;

    % Name graph            
    \node   [
            font = \bfseries,
            below = 2pt of \name.south
            ]
            {\name} ;   

    % Vertical lines and labels (should be 4 equidistant vertical lines) 
    \foreach \s [count=\i] in \values {
        \coordinate  (top) at  ($(\name.north west)!\i/5!(\name.north east)$) ;
        \coordinate (bottom) at ($(\name.south west)!\i/5!(\name.south east)$) ;
        \draw [dashed] (top)  --  (bottom) ;
        % Data to be plotted when this works
        };

} % end foreach \name


\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't really get, what you are trying to achieve. Am I right, when I guess you want to set the `\def\labelsM{85, 10, 55, 75}` for example into the four corners of the first rectangle?

Comment: I just saw two typos and have updated the code. In each of the three boxes I want to plot the four values, moving from `\labelsM` in the first, to `\labelsC` in the second to `\labelsP` in the third. That's what I expected `\values` to point to in each iteration, but when the nested loop runs, it only seems to run once.

Comment: foreach doesn't expand `\values` completly but only one level deep. So it sees only `\labelsM` and not the values. Expand `\values` at least once before using it: `\expandafter\let\expandafter\values\values`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks Ulrike. However I'm having trouble understanding the command. The `let` replaces `\values` with `\expandafter\values`, why, though, do you then expand this also? (If I'm totally misunderstanding, please explain.)

Comment: \expandafter expands the next but one command. So the first \expandafter expands the second \expandafter which expands the second \values to \labelsX then TeX continues with the \let command. At the end you get \let\values\labelsX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

foreach doesn't expand `\values` completly but only one level deep. So it sees only `\labelsM` and not the values. Expand `\values` at least once before using it:

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\values\values
```

`\expandafter` expands the next but one command. So the first `\expandafter` expands the second `\expandafter` which expands the second `\values` to `\labelsX` then TeX continues with the `\let` command. At the end you get `\let\values\labelsX`.)

Comment: This of course assumes you know that `\values` expands to a single token (which is the case here).

Comment: Isn't it smpler to do `\edef\values{\values}` (and to have full expnsion) ?

Comment: @Kpym: In the example that should work too. But it depends on the contents of the `\labelX` commands if more then one expansion is "safe".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer or "needed" ;) But you are right, it depends on the content of `labelX` if we need one, two or full expansion.